# Creating a Task in Apex

Tags: apex, soql, debugging, tasks

I'm trying to create a Task in Apex, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's my actual code:

```
RecordType rt = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Some Record Type' AND SobjectType = 'Task'];
Task logCall = new Task(WhatId = friend.Id, RecordTypeId = rt.Id, Type = 'General Task', Subject = 'Here\'s my subject', Description = 'Description');

System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@');

try {
    insert logCall;
} catch (DmlException e) {
    ApexPages.addMessages(e);
    return appendId(Page.SomeView);
}
```

When I execute that, there are no error returned to my view. When I check at the developer console, I get this error message:

```
15:35:28:208 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [3]|this.message|"You do not have priv (40 more) ..."|0x67e122
15:35:28:208 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [4]|this.message2|"You can not modify t (61 more) ..."|0x67e122
```

Any idea how to prevent that from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to check your profile, it looks like you do not permissions on that object.

Comment: I have a System Administrator profile with every privilege enabled, so this is probably not the problem.

Comment: What is exactly `You do not have priv...` and `You can not modify t`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the code is working. The reason I couldn't see it from my object Activity History is because I wasn't filling the DueDate and the Status.

So, a quick `ActivityDate = Date.today()` and `Status = 'Completed'` did the job.

Comment: Strange error message then. Normally it would show you a message like "A mandatory field is null" or something else...

Comment: I know, I don't get it. The main explanation I have right now is that the error might have been triggered by something else.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the SysAdmin profile's allowed Task Record Types (this is enforced even if you're SysAdmin, on any object).
2. Check if your "friend" object whatever it is that you're passing as `WhatId`) has "Allow Activities" ticked.
3. Consider using normal Debug Logs or just open raw log so you can see the full message.